# to mock method calls inside spring aspect around method

Tags: mockito

I want to mock method calls inside @Aspect class.

I have class Student.

```
public class Student{
public String getName()
{
//
}
}

I have an Aspect class 

@Aspect
@Component
public class StudentAspect{

@Autowired
B b;
@Around( // the Student class get method)
public void around(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint)
{
b.doSomething();
}
}
```

I want to test StudentAspect using Mockito. I programatically created a proxy for Student class so that i could trigger StudentAspect class. However, I am not able mock Class b object. Can anyone please help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AspectJProxyFactory for testing aspects . AspectJ-based proxy factory, allowing for programmatic building of proxies which include AspectJ aspects .

Example:

```
@Test
public void testStudentAspect() {
    B testBean = new B();

    AspectJProxyFactory factory = new AspectJProxyFactory();
    factory.setTarget(testBean);

    CounterAspect myCounterAspect = new CounterAspect();
    factory.addAspect(myCounterAspect);

    ITestBean proxyTestBean = factory.getProxy();

    proxyTestBean.doSomething();

    //assert
}
```